# Clustered MDBs with Spring

Tags: java, spring, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I have an existing spring/JPA application and some of the business logic I want to run in parallel. Years ago on a telecoms app I had a similar requirement and we handled this by executing the parallel code on worker nodes in a JBoss cluster. The master node would farm out the jobs to a queue, and the worker nodes would pick them up via MDBs.

I could do the same now, but I'm not sure what is the best way to transition from Spring/JPA to a clustered/parallel environment. Maybe Spring supports something like this and I don't have to get into the bloat that is JBoss again.

cheers,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

All Spring provides is a nicer API on to existing services, it doesn't provide any of its own.  If you want distributed messaging, then you'll need to use a technology that provides that service. if it's JMS-compliant, then Spring will make life a bit easier for you, but that's as far as it goes.

So sticking with a JBoss cluster is one option. Alternatively, go with a more lightweight solution, such as HornetQ, ActiveMQ (both JMS implementations that can be embedded in any old application), or a compute grid like Terracotta, Infinigrid or GigaSpaces. Spring doesn't provide explicit support for compute grids, but they may be a better fit for your problem.